# Linux How to communicate with a PCI driver

Tags: linux, device-driver, pci

I'm new on driver programming. So I 'm faced with some "problems".

I wrote a PCI driver. The question is now How can a app communicate with this driver.

My purpose is to write a test app for the driver. It's a kind of "basic research" to learn the driver programming.

Normally I would say over the device file in `/dev`. But my file in this directory has no permission for reading or writing except root. So how communicate? Via attribute files?

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense. If you wrote the driver, you should have provided the means for an app to communicate with it (that's part of writing the driver).

Comment: @KenWhite Of course, sry for the missing information. My purpose is to write a test app for the driver. It's a kind of "basic research" to learn the driver programming.

Comment: Again, if you wrote the driver, you should know how the test app needs to communicate with it. Your question makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @KenWhite `Normally I would say over the device file in /dev. But my file in this directory has no permission for reading or writing except root.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the node in `/dev` is the correct approach. What you need to do is to fix the permissions.

You can do that using `chmod` but you'll have to do that every time you reboot. A better solution is to create a udev rule which matches the ID of your PCI device. Then, you can run the `chmod` in the rule.

Documentation: [Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Isn't there a possibility to do that direct in the driver?

Comment: No, because on modern Linux systems, the device node is created by udev. The main reason for this is that the sysadmin can assign special permissions (like certain groups) to a dev node. If that was compiled into your driver, there was no simple way to change that.